# Cant print sum in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

i have the next problem.

I have this code :

```
 $_Query = "select sum(attribute19) as total from INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B";
                   rs1= Gdr.consultar($_Query,2);
                   while(rs1.next()){
                       out.print(rs1.getString("total"));
                   }
```

But nothing displays in the screen, i think the problem is with the sum function, because if I change the code to

```
 $_Query = "select attribute19 as total from INV.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B";
                   rs1= Gdr.consultar($_Query,2);
                   while(rs1.next()){
                       out.print(rs1.getString("total"));
                   }
```

then with this code, all is displayed in the screen, maybe i am writing some code in the wrong way

I am using oracle and JSP.

Hope you can help me

Comment: what is the type of attribute19 column in db? Maybe its varchar?

Comment: Do any rows contain `NULL` for the value of `attribute19`?

Comment: Nulls shouldn't be a problem for `sum()`, they're ignored. Why `getString()` to get a number? What value do you get if you run the sum query directly in the database?

Comment: attribute19 is varchar2, i used a to_number function before but didnt work

Comment: some values are null in this column

Comment: Since you're storing numbers as strings, it's likely you have something in that column that can't be converted - so you'd get an ORA-01722 error from your sum, but not from pulling individual values as strings; but in that case your `Gdr.consultar()` function would have to be squashing that error and returning an empty result set.

Comment: @AlexPoole here is my function:                                                                           `public ResultSet consultar(String sql,int TC){
         try{
            Cr = conectar(TC);
            st=con.createStatement();
            res= st.executeQuery(sql);
         }
        catch(SQLException e){
            return null;
        }
        return res;
     }`

Comment: Please add things like that to the question. So, you are hiding the exception - why not *at least* print it? Your `while` loop would get a null pointer exception if that function returned null though. You still haven't said what happens if you do the `sum` directly in the database, e.g. via SQL\*Plus.

Comment: @AlexPoole this query returns all the correct data in sql developer or even toad, the problem seems to be here in java.

Comment: Well, are you getting an exception in Java? You'll need to change your code to see that. That could still be happening, say if your column includes decimals and your Java session's locale doesn't match your other clients.

Comment: @AlexPoole where can i check that about decimals ??

Comment: Start by *not hiding your exceptions*. It's just a guess. You can query `nls_session_parameters` to see what `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is set to in each client/app.

Comment: @AlexPoole This is the query result : NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS .,

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this format:

```
   sum(to_number(itel.attribute19,'999D999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = .,'))
```